# How to split a list by character and new Set in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I have a list as below:

```
list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a,b,f"]
```

I use new_Set(list) and get below result:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a,b,f"]
```

I would like to get unique object, how to split them by ','?

What I need is :

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `join` the entire array to create a comma separated string and split it at `,`:

```
new Set(String(list).split(","))
```

or

```
new Set(list.join(",").split(","))
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a,b,f"],
      unique = new Set(list.join(",").split(","))
      
console.log(
  Array.from(unique)
)
```

Comment: They are all Set object, I need a list, and I need to let another object to judge, whether they are equal value, another object is a single String object

Comment: @RainbowGong please check the snippet. You can use  `Array.from(set)` or `[...set]` to convert the set to an array.

Comment: hey, do you know how to let a button in force after 5 sconds, and let html element highlight JS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414406/how-to-let-a-button-in-force-after-5-sconds-and-let-html-element-highlight-js

Answer (score 2):

You could flat map the splitted values.

```js
const
    list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a,b,f"],
    unique = new Set(list.flatMap(s => s.split(',')));

console.log(...unique);
```

Comment: They are all Set object, I need a list, and I need to let another object to judge, whether they are equal value, another object is a single String object

Comment: do you have an example for it? please add this information to the question.

Comment: hey, do you know how to let a button in force after 5 sconds, and let html element highlight JS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414406/how-to-let-a-button-in-force-after-5-sconds-and-let-html-element-highlight-js

Answer (score 0):

Just [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
console.log("a,b,f".split(','))
```